# can't set source of imagecropper.Forms

Tags: xamarin, github, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to use the nuget ImageCropper.Forms of this link https://github.com/stormlion227/ImageCropper.Forms . I already fulfilled the setup but can't run the example of the page, it is the next:

to Show ImageCropper page.

```
new ImageCropper()
{
    Success = (imageFile) =>
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            imageView.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(imageFile);
        });
    }
}.Show(this);
```

and tell me that imageViewis not declared, I thought I have to declare an image and use that for the imagesource but didn't work. Someone have an idea?

Comment: Do you have an  `ImageView` that is `x:name` as `imageView` in your XAML, or an instance var of ImageView?

Comment: I can't declare an ImageView, it doesn't appear. I am using xamarin forms.

Comment: Are you using the [`Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin) view?